# SWIF Error Message: Instantiated view controller ... but didn't get a UICollectionView.'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting an error message that is typically associated with a missing IBOutlet but when I add one I get even more errors. I have found a few answers on SO but none of them have worked. What am I doing wrong?

**Error Message:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
> '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller
> with identifier "UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r" from storyboard "Main",
> but didn't get a UICollectionView.'

```
import UIKit
import Photos

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
        
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        grabPhotos()
    }
    
    func grabPhotos(){
    
        let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        
        if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions){
            if fetchResult.count > 0 {
                for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{
                    imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i), targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                        image, error in
                        self.imageArray.append(image!)
                    })
                }
            } else {
                print("you do not have any photos")
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 1
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a non-UICollectionViewController in your Storyboard, and you set its class to `ViewController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start a new project, Xcode gives you a default `UIViewController` with custom class `ViewController`:

[image]

You cannot simply change the class to:

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```

Instead, delete the default controller from your Storyboard and add a new `UICollectionViewController`:

[image]

Note that the Custom Class shows as `UICollectionViewController` (in gray, because it is the default class). You can now change that to `ViewController` (and on the Attributes Inspector pane set it as `Is Initial View Controller`).

Comment: Thanks DonMag! That cleared the error message but my code is not pulling up any of the images in the photo library. Do you by chance know why it is not pulling up any images? It is just a blank white screen.

Comment: @Part_Time_Nerd - quick look at your code... You are calling `.reloadData()` on your collection view ***only if*** `fetchResult.count` is Zero. You also need to call it after you have appended the images to the array.